# How do I export my java project so it can run without the help of the IDE (netbeans)?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I recently completed a java project using Netbeans.After pushing clean and build button it creates a jar file.the problem is that the jar file won't connect with database(MySQL).It works perfectly while it's still in the IDE.How do I solve this problem so that I can install my software into another machine?

Comment: probably you are using libraries from the ide path, that you don't put in your .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the suggestions below might help.

- Since your jar file connects to a database file, you need to read the
  parameters like "url", "username" , "password" from some file(this is
  called externalization)
- Also check if you are having the database driver jar in your "lib"
  while you try to run the jar outside of your IDE.